# Proof by induction on $k$

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone give me some pointers on where to start on this question. I have tried to do a base step for $k=1$ but its just too complicated and I don't know what to try:

$$\int_0^x t^ke^{\lambda t}\,\mathrm dt = \frac{(-1)^{k+1}k!}{\lambda^{k+1}}  + \sum_{i=0}^k\frac{(-1)^ik^i}{\lambda^{i+1}}x^{k-i}e^{\lambda x}.$$

We are given that:
$$\int_0^x x^{k}\,\mathrm  =\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}.$$

Prove by induction on $k$.

I know this looks complicated, I'm just so confused!

Comment: I've tried to $\LaTeX$ this, and I hope I did not get confused or confuse the statement to the worse. Bubbles, could you please check my edit?

Comment: @Bubblez775 , read here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117  As you wrote it, your question is almost uncomprehensible.

Comment: Thanks for latexing it. I have just edited one bit but apart from that it was great. Big help!!!

Comment: Why is this listed as linear algebra?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* The induction step shouts for partial integration.
And use $k=0$ as base case.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ By changing variables,  it can be expressed in terms of an [incomplete gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function), which satisfies a recurrence relation, obtainable by integrating by parts as follows

$$ \begin{eqnarray}\gamma(s,x) &\ =\ & (s\!-\!1)\ \gamma (s\!-\!1,x) &-& x^{s-1} e^{-x} \\ \\
\int_0^x{t^{s-1} d(-e^{-t})} &=& \int_0^x{d(t^{s-1})\ e^{-t}} &-& x^{s-1} e^{-x}\end{eqnarray}$$

One can do similarly in your case (or change variables and reuse incomplete gamma proofs ).